# Flutter easy loading, how do you edit its text style (underline, font family, size)?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi so basically I added an import that which allows user to use "Easyloading".
This is the package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_easyloading)

Basically you add style or let default do it. However, I customized mine:

```
EasyLoading.instance
      ..displayDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 1500)
      ..loadingStyle = EasyLoadingStyle.light
      ..indicatorType = EasyLoadingIndicatorType.wave
      ..maskType = EasyLoadingMaskType.clear
      ..userInteractions = false;
```

Reason I edited, because I want to have much control as possible when it comes to style, unfortunately editting it or not, I was not able to edit the text as much as I want to.

```
EasyLoading.show(status: 'loading...');
```

When I do this action it displays well, However I wish to edit its Boldness text, underline, and "font family style".

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                EasyLoading.instance
                  ..displayDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 2000)
                  ..backgroundColor = Colors.white
                  ..indicatorColor = Colors.black
                  ..maskColor = Colors.black
                  ..userInteractions = false;
                EasyLoading.show(status: 'loading...');
                Navigator.push(this.context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterAccount()));
              },
              child: Text("Register"),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

See I studied the plugin and they have not used any kind of styling to the text. They have just mentioned Color and font size. So you have to add those from there according to your wish,
at the code definition which you can access when you import the plugin at the top by clicking view definitions.

So at this place in container.dart as shown in the package definition here
[EASY LOADING EDIT](https://github.com/huangjianke/flutter_easyloading/blob/master/lib/src/widgets/container.dart)

```
Text(
                _status,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: EasyLoadingTheme.textColor,
                  fontSize: EasyLoadingTheme.fontSize,
                ),
                textAlign: EasyLoadingTheme.textAlign,
              )
```

You can add your own style in the TextStyle.
Hope this could help :)

Comment: Hi krish I was able to edit align, size, color, but font family style, underline, bold, or italic; wasnt so much.

Comment: hi Krish, so I added my raised button code, inside on pressed: I added the customization there, but like I said I didnt found anything that takes of underline of the text.

Comment: hi Krish, this is the image [ https://imgur.com/OAUNKDu ], as you can see I was able to edit colors of indicator, text color, but the 2 underlines i dont know how, I just really wish to disable them or delete them, lames the design haha

Comment: Okay , I can see that. Umm you want these pop up kind of message. Ugh so is it okay if I tell you another good way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
EasyLoading.instance
..displayDuration = const Duration(seconds: 3)
..indicatorType = EasyLoadingIndicatorType.cubeGrid
..loadingStyle = EasyLoadingStyle.custom
..indicatorSize = 45.0
..radius = 10.0
..progressColor = Colors.blue.shade900
..backgroundColor = Colors.blueGrey
..indicatorColor = Colors.white
..textColor = Colors.white
..textStyle = const TextStyle(fontSize:22,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic )
..maskColor = Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7)
..userInteractions = true
..maskType = EasyLoadingMaskType.custom
..dismissOnTap = isDismiss;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.